# Makita EA7900P Chainsaw Carburetor Fuel Lines

Tags: chainsaw

Replacing carburetor on chainsaw Makita EA7900P, I don't remember where each fuel line goes from the carburetor.

Comment: I'd suggest that this be moved to [mechanics.se]. Sure, chainsaws are used around the house and I've even used them _on_ a house (hey, I'd never heard of a Sawzall back then!), but this isn't about that, it's about repairing an engine, and that's their purview.

Answer (score 2):

Use a small length of tubing or a straw to puff some air into each hose. The supply hose will bubble through the fuel filter into the gas in the tank. The return hose will just blow into the air.